# How to make an export table to file from prompt of mysql?

Tags: mysql

subj. into table_name.sql file. I would like to know it, official docs of MySQL has info only about how to dump whole database, or I a bad surfer.

**updated:**

Ok, trying:

```
mysql> mysqldump db_name tbl_name;
```

or

```
mysql> mysqldump root mypass123 db_name tbl_name;
```

or

```
mysql> mysqldump -root -mypass123 db_name tbl_name;
```

always a same error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysql dump personal' at line 1

**updated:**

yes, it's really from shell (instead of prompt):

> mysql\bin>mysqldump -root -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql
>
> Enter password: *********
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
>   'ODBC'@'localhost' (using pas sword: YES) when trying to connect

I have a password and my user is root, why bad now?

**FOUND IT:**

must be -uroot instead of simple root or -root.

One moment, now I need to find that file. smiling. Ok. He is in the current bin directory, maybe a right way will be using full path: > C:\tbl_name.sql

Thank you all!

Comment: is it necessary to be inside mysql prompt?

Comment: no, I'm just want to know if it's possible or not. Interesting.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you need to run `mysqldump` from your shell, not from inside `mysql`.

Comment: you dont need to enter in `mysql`, `mysqldump.exe` is another application for dumping data. try from root directory ex : `mysql\bin>mysqldump ...`

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul how to access mysql from the root directory? How to go in the mode mysql\bin>?

Answer (score 4):

you can export a table just using

```
mysql\bin> mysqldump -uuser -p db_name table_name, table_name  > table_name.sql
```

[mysql dump docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

```
mysql\bin> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
mysql\bin> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name [tbl_name]
```

Comment: check my addition , `> table_name.sql`

Comment: why twice the table name ?

Comment: If you want to export multiple tables, you need to seperate them using a space, not a comma.